# If the KJV is still in copyright in the UK could I have a problem if people buy something quoting it from the US?

Tags: copyright, united-kingdom

I'm creating a Christian game with KJV quotes which will be printed and published -via self-publishing- in the US. I understand the KJV is in the public domain worldwide, except for the UK. Could I have a problem if people from the UK bought the game and it was sent to them from the US?

Comment: The KJV is patented in the UK which means that only certain organisations can print it. Although similar  to copyright the basis has nothing to do with copyright, but with preventing people claiming something is biblical when it isn't.  (effectively claiming royal endorsement for something that has not been endorsed)   As such copyright law, per se,  is not relevant to this question. . . If you claim that a quote is from the KJV and actually it isn't  then in theory you could run into trouble. I agree that legal advice should be sought from competent lawyers - just not copyright ones.

Comment: @davidlol Fascinating nuance. Never heard of that before. It sounds like an accurate quotation wouldn't be a problem.

Comment: @Davidlol where do "KJV is patented in the UK" or "only certain organisations can print it" come from, please?

Where does  KJV being still in copyright in the UK come from?

If KJV had copyright in the UK, what would let it out of copyright in the US?

How might copyright, patent or anything else prevent anyone claiming something was biblical?

What could that have to do with royal endorsement?

When you claim a quote is from the KJV but it isn't, what trouble could you could run into, and how or why?

Since the context specifically is copyright, why rule out copyright lawyers?